# How to implement popup menu with custom layout in android 2.3

Tags: android, menu, popup, custom-controls

I would like to be able to achieve the functionality that the Whats Up application has. When you click the attach icon on the top-right of the activity (when in chat mode), a popup appears (that enables you to select weather to attach image, video, etc.). I do belive this is possible to achieve using the PopupMenu available in the android SDK but its applicable for API 11+

[PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)

Is it possible to do the same for android 2.3? Even with actionbarsherlock? By the way I am not interested in dialogs or context menus, they just dont have the same look for what I need.

any suggestions would be appreciated,
thank you

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the new v7 support library to achieve actionbar functionality pre 3.0.

> New v7 appcompat library:
>
> Added ActionBar to allow implementation of the action bar user interface design 
>   pattern back to Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. Use of this class requires that you 
>   implement your activity by extending the new ActionBarActivity class.

[Android Actionbar using support library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)